Error with apt update
I am trying to update the system. But I get an error message.
apt update

Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (199.232.46.132), connection timed out Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (199.232.46.132), connection timed out Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bookworm-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:48::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


This must be a network error, could you write the output of ping 4.2.2.4 and lshw -class network?
